# Change registation mail text to customer

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to `opencart` , I am trying to change the text message that is going to the customer as a mail when he register in website , I have changed the text in file from the path `catalog/model/account/customer.php` still the text message was not changed , can anybody suggest what are the files that need be changed for this?

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit language files, not the template for text changes. It's located in:

**/catalog/language/your-language/mail/** folder